# mirror full website1 and all links to specific website2

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I want to mirror a website that will be taken down soon, the problem im facing at the moment is simple -> mirror whole website1 and all links (will be files/images/similiar) to website2 too, so i got a nice "merged" mirror.

-Therefore the Question would be:

How to do this with wget? Are the other ways to solve this problem (if not possible with wget)?

-Logic Example:

The Website is http://example.org and it will get mirrored (wget -mk). wget should also mirror every content being hosted on http://foo.bar too but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what you are looking for:

```
wget -mk -w 20 http://www.example.com/ --exclude-domains sunsite.foo.edu --domains yahoo.com,google.com
```

> - **m** Turn on options suitable for mirroring; time-stamping & infinite recursion depth keeping directory listings.
> - **k** After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing.
> - **w SECONDS** Introduce a delay between accesses to the server.
> - **--exclude-domains DOMAIN-LIST** Domains that are not to be followed.
> - **--domains DOMAIN-LIST** A set domains to be followed, a comma-separated list of domains.

Comment: im looking for a way to do --include-domain <LIST> not exclude specific sites.

Comment: @K1773R Checkout my [updated answer](http://superuser.com/a/522167/178243), you may include a list of domains also

Comment: --domains was what i was looking for, ty!

Answer (score 0):

rysnc will mirror the files

```
rysnc -auvz source destination
```

the -u flag will skip files that are newer on the destination, so this is probably what you want.

Comment: the second website has no links nor directory listings.

Comment: Why does that matter? :) wget -m download the first site, and merge together with rysnc?

Comment: first site got tons of links to other sites, but i want only specific ones to be followed (to foo.bar as example)

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -p -k http://example.org
```

The -p will get you all the required elements to view the site correctly (css, images, etc). The -k will change all links (to include those for CSS & images) to allow you to view the page offline as it appeared online.